# Assigning string group ID in pandas

Tags: pandas, grouping

I have a data frame (data)

```
Col 1   Col 2    Combination    
1        2         (1,2)  
3        4         (3,4)
1        2         (1,2)
2        3         (2,3)  
4        6         (4,6) 
3        4         (3,4)
```

I want to assign a group ID based on Col 1 and Col 2 as a categorical variable not a numerical one

My output needed

```
Col 1   Col 2    Combination    GroupID 
1        2         (1,2)           A
3        4         (3,4)           C 
1        2         (1,2)           A
2        3         (2,3)           B 
4        6         (4,6)           D
3        4         (3,4)           C
```

The GroupID need to be a categorical data type need not to be numerical and can follow any order.

I have tried this code but the GroupID column is treated as numerical datatype

```
data['GroupID']=data1.groupby(['Col','Col2']).ngroup()

data['GroupID'] = data['GroupID'].astype('category')
```

Can anyone suggest a proper way to deal with this issue?

Comment: I don't see why it cannot be numerical, but you can `map` it using `(data.groupby(['Col1','Col2']).ngroup()+65).map(chr)`.